# How to solve class not found error in magento 1.9?

Tags: extensions, class, magento1.9.2.3

I have try to install stamped.io extension, after install back-end showing following error if i click stamped.io setting.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class
>   'Stamped_Core_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form_Button' not found in
>   /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:590
>   Stack trace: #0 /home/abc/public_html/app/Mage.php(533):
>   Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getBlockSingleton('\n ...') #1
>   /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(310):
>   Mage::getBlockSingleton('\n ...') #2
>   /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(229):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset),
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element),
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)) #3
>   /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(164):
>   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->_initGroup(Object(Varien_Data_Form),
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element),
>   Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)) #4
>   /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Confi
>   in /home/abc/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on
>   line 590

**app/code/community/Stamped/Core/Block/AdminHtml/System/Config/Form/Button.php**

```
<?php
class Stamped_Core_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form_Button extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field
{
    /*
     * template
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('stamped/system/config/button.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * return html
     *
     * @param  Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getElementHtml(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        return $this->_toHtml();
    }
}
```

How to solve the class missing error?

Comment: can you please update your code where you have use the `Form/Button.php`

Comment: @RakeshVarma Pls check with my updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, I could identify that:

> app/code/community/Stamped/Core/Block/AdminHtml/System/Config/Form/Button.php

path should be:

> app/code/community/Stamped/Core/Block/Adminhtml/System/Config/Form/Button.php

Notice the typo in **AdminHtml**, which should be **Adminhtml**.

Please fix this and let me know if you find any other problem further.

Comment: Great,  how to find this kind of error? Recommend any editor or something else?

Comment: There is no magical editor trick. Just follow the core principles of Magento for naming conventions.

Comment: I have magento in localhost, here app/code/community/Stamped/Core/Block/AdminHtml/System/Config/Form/Button.php working, may i know the difference?

Comment: Maybe you are using the Windows system for the localhost. There is a major difference between a Windows and a Linux system. The folder names **AdminHtml**, **adminhtml**, and **Adminhtml** are same for Windows, but these are threee different folders for Linux.

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows for testing and development. Thank you for your explanation.